# PhantomJS and jquery screen scraping - no output

Tags: phantomjs

I am attempting to do screen scraping using phantom js.

I have copied some phantomjs code from this site: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/534-How-to-scrape-web-pages-with-PhantomJS-and-jQuery

Starting with that script, I have modified into this: http://jsfiddle.net/dqfTa/ (see javascript)

My aim is to collect the prices from a website, which are the inner html of the ".price" tags, into a javascript array. Right now I am trying to console.log() them to my screen.

I am running phantomjs v1.6 and jquery v1.8 through the ubuntu 12.04 console. I am setting the user agent to "iPhone".

Here is my output:

```
nwo@aws-chaos-us-w-1:~/sandbox$ phantomjs  usingjqueryandphantom.js
hello
success
============================================
Step "0"
============================================
```

It never gets past step 0. Take a look at my code, I did a  `console.log("h1");` but it won't output it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried debugging it using `--remote-debugger-port=SOMEPORT` and then going to `http://localhost:SOMEPORT` ?

Comment: Are you running the JavaScript within the context of the page you want to scrape? It won't do anything outside the scope of the page.

Answer (score 4):

Phantomjs requires you to hook into the console output coming from it's page context. From the [API reference](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference):

> This callback is invoked when there is a JavaScript console message on
>   the web page. The callback may accept up to three arguments: the
>   string for the message, the line number, and the source identifier.
>
> By default, console messages from the web page are not displayed.
>   Using this callback is a typical way to redirect it.

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log("This message came from the webpage: "+ msg);
};
```